# Split on space if preceded by a specific substring

Tags: php, regex, string, split, explode

```
$text = "This is /n my text /n wow";

$quotes = explode('/n',$text);
```

This would split the string into "This is" "My text" "wow"

but I want it to leave the string "/n" as it is, instead of cutting it off,
the output should look like this:

> "This is /n" "my text /n" "wow"

Comment: [What are you trying to solve?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Answer (score 3):

Explode your string into an array and then append the separator onto each element of the resulting array.

```
$sep    = "/n";
$text   = "This is /n my text /n wow";
$quotes = explode($sep,$text);
$quotes = array_map(function($val) use ($sep) {
     return $val . $sep;
}, $quotes);
$last_key = count($quotes)-1;
$quotes[$last_key] = rtrim($quotes[$last_key], $sep);
```

(Might need to `trim($val)` as well).

Comment: I doubt he wants to add it to the last item.

Answer (score 3):

Have you looked into using the [`preg_split()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) function. Per the documentation:

> preg_split — Split string by a regular expression

Using this function, apply a positive lookbehind that matches spaces followed by a preceding `/n` string.

```
$quotes= preg_split("/(?<=\/n) /", $text);
```

You can test that this is the desired functionality by doing `print_r($quotes);` after the above statement. This output from the `print_r` function will looks similar to the following:

```
Array ( [0] => This is /n [1] => my text /n [2] => wow )
```

You may need to use `trim()` on the values to clear off leading and trailing whitespace but overall it seems to do what you're asking.

---

**DEMO:**

If you want to test this functionality out, try copying the following code block and pasting it into the <kbd>CodeSpace</kbd> window on http://phpfiddle.org.

```
<?php
$text = "This is /n my text /n wow";
$values = preg_split("/(?<=\/n) /", $text);
print_r($values);
?>
```

Select the <kbd>Run - F9</kbd> option to see the output. My apologies for the copy and paste demo example. I couldn't figure out how to create a dedicated URL like some of the other fiddle programs.

Comment: @l'L'l Are you sure? In the OP's code, he/she has the `/n` character that they want in the string not the newline `\n` character. I changed my phpfiddle to use `\n` and it returned the unaltered string. I could be off though. I'm not very good with regex.

Answer (score 1):

If you have only one possible separator then you can simply append it to the tokens that `explode` returned. However, if you're asking this question, e.g. because you have multiple possible separators and need to know which one separated two tokens, then [`preg_split`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) might work for you. E.g. for separators `','` and `';'`:

```
$matches = preg_match('/(,|;)/', $text, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
```